# Joomla Login Function

Tags: php, joomla

For logging into Joomla im using

```
$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login(array('username'=>$username,    'password'=>$password));
```

is there any way to pass the login function a remember me option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `login()` takes a second argument where you can set the remember option:

```
$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login(array('username'=>$username,    'password'=>$password), array('remember' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

`login` accepts second argument, `options` - it's pointed out in the function's docstring:

```
/**
 * Login authentication function
 *
 * @param   array   Array('username' => string, 'password' => string)
 * @param   array   Array('remember' => boolean)
 *
 * @see JApplication::login
 */
public function login($credentials, $options = array())
```